# How to clear database exception

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, exception

The code runs perfect if the user does not make an error, however, if an error is made the program does not crash, but  it will not do anything else it is programmed to do. When I click add again, as my program goes to save the changes to the database it jumps into my catch statement without saving. How do I clear the error after catching it so I can add another user to the database?

To make it more clear:

Say you enter Test, Test in the `textbox` as soon as the program is open. You will get this exception

> InnerException = {"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Users'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Users'. The duplicate key value is (Test, Test).The statement has been terminated."}.

If you then try to enter Check, Check you will get the exception

> InnerException = {"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Users'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Users'. The duplicate key value is (Test, Test).The statement has been terminated."}.

If the name is changed why am I getting the same error. When debugging if you check for the name being used in: `db.Users.Add(user)` it shows Check, Check so it is not like it isn't changing the `user.Name`

```
try
        {
            if (addNameTextBox.Text.Trim().Length == 0 || addTitleTextBox.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
                return;
            var user = new User();
            user.Name = addNameTextBox.Text.Trim();
            user.Title = addTitleTextBox.Text.Trim();
            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            addNameTextBox.Text = "";
            addTitleTextBox.Text = "";
            AutoCompleteNameTextBox();
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException)
        {
            databaseErrorLabel.Visible = true;
            databaseErrorLabel.Text = "User with this name is already in database";
        }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187537/discussion-on-question-by-mr-finch-how-to-clear-database-exception).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all boils down to "how to roll back additions in EF on exception".

Unless you start over with a brand new instance of your database context, you need to roll back the addition to the Users entity:
keep a reference to the added User object, and set its `EntityState = EntityState.Detached` on exception.

Comment: Note that this approach is only sufficient if the context is not in an ambient transaction. Usually SaveChanges runs in its own transaction, rolls it back when an error occurs and NOT change the entity states in its ChangeTracker. If there is an ambient transaction however and an exception is caught, the transaction is not rolled back (there may be data changes from previous SaveChanges() calls), meaning some statements may have gone through and changed the data, while the entity states stay the same. To deal with this, use SavePoints or only add one entity at a time in addition to detaching.